# On the fly projection not working in QuantumGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to put a point layer of cities on top of a shapefile of counties in QuantumGIS.  I have on the 'On the Fly' turned on and both files are in the same projection system.  However, the point file is not showing up on the county file and both have different coordinate systems for some reason.  How to I get the layers aligned?

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21691/qgis-layers-no-longer-overlay-when-enable-on-the-fly-crs-transformation-is-on?rq=1

Comment: check that you have a prj file first and that it contains the projection you think it is second.

Comment: I restarted the program without the towns layer.  Then I turned OTF back on, downloaded the towns layer again and projected it.  This time it worked.  May have been a problem with the download.